# Windows BATCH file producing NULL from an Array

Tags: arrays, windows, loops, batch-file, for-loop

Using the following within a Bat file on Windows 7 produces a null as shown here:

```
for %J in ((**null**)) do echo %J   <<<===This is when gets displayed.
```

There are a large number of references which is why the array is being used 
instead of the "set DIR_LIST(.\Dir1*.txt  .\Dir2*.txt  .\Dir3*.txt)"

```
set DIR_LIST[1]=.\Dir1\*.txt
set DIR_LIST[2]=.\Dir2\*.txt
set DIR_LIST[3]=.\Dir3\*.txt

for %%J in (%DIR_LIST%) do echo %%J
```

Any suggestions as to what needs to be corrected?

Comment: The first line should throw an error because you need to use `%%J`, but I don't have any idea what you mean with »null« here.

Comment: @Јοеу He means that when he runs the batch file, the console shows displays the first code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set DIR_LIST[1]=.\Dir1\*.txt
set DIR_LIST[2]=.\Dir2\*.txt
set DIR_LIST[3]=.\Dir3\*.txt

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%J in ('set DIR_LIST[') do echo %%J

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%J in ('set DIR_LIST[') do for %%F in (%%J) do echo %%F
```

I am not sure what of the two you are trying to get

Comment: After incorporating into the actual code, using the first command works perfectly. The 2nd command only printed out the last two items.